# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value of attribute "id" associated with an element type "Employee" must not contain the '<' character. at

Tags: java, xml

I have the Issue when I'm trying to read XML parsing and I have input XML contains some special characters like &,<,> and "".
While parsing XML using SAXParse api getting below Excpetions.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value of attribute "id" associated with an element type "Employee" must not contain the '<' character. at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
```

Please let me know how to replace special character before XML Parsing happens.
If any body have piece of code please share.

Its great help !.
-Vishwanath

Comment: Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for reference.

Comment: Your input is not well-formed XML so you won't be able to read it with an XML parser. You need to change the program that generates this bad XML.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to escape the following characters**:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

Comment: I Can't change input XML file. from programmatically I want to replace special character of XML Tags.